# Consider the mean of GROUP_CONCAT values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the following and I have used `GROUP_CONCAT(val) as LIST_Value`.  I want to consider the mean of the this column and also the length of the values in each row.  This `AVG(GROUP_CONCAT(val))` and `GROUP_CONCAT(AVG(val))` did not solve that.

I also read this link: [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns) But, I could not find the answer for my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the average, do it separately from the group concatenation.

```
SELECT point_id, date, GROUP_CONCAT(val) AS LIST_Value, AVG(val) AS AVG_Value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY point_id, date
```